# Не работает setImageResource

Tags: java, android, android-studio, анимация, android-imageview

Осваивая `AndroidStudio`,  столкнулся с такой проблемой. Следующий код должен рисовать на экране бутылку, и далее с помощью многократного вызова `fly()` , например по таймеру, она должна лететь вниз. Что происходит на самом деле: ничего, просто белый пустой экран без каких-либо признаков жизни. Объясните, пожалуйста, что я здесь сделал не так?

```
 public class Bottle {
    ImageView bottle;
    private float y;
    private float size;
    private  float x;

    public Bottle(MainActivity main) {
        size =(float)(MainActivity.screenWidth/(Math.random()*5+5));
        bottle = new ImageView(main);
        main.addContentView(bottle,new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)size, (int)size));
        bottle.setImageResource(R.drawable.bottle);
        y=size/2;
        x = (float) Math.random()*(MainActivity.screenWidth -size)+size/2;
        bottle.setY(y);
        bottle.setX(x);
        bottle.setScaleX(size);
        bottle.setScaleY(size);
    }

    public void fly() {
        if (y <= MainActivity.screenHeight + size / 2) {
            y += 5;
            bottle.setY(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Лучше все это удалите, подход неверен в принципе.

Comment: Для инспирации, к примеру: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sunrise.php

Comment: А какой вариант реализации верный? Anumation использовать нельзя, не разрешит препод. Мне показалось, что других вариантов особо нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае, как мне кажется, самый простой способ, рисовать вашу бутылку на канве.

Вот тут неплохо расписано для начала.
http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/311-urok-141-risovanie-dostup-k-canvas.html

Манипулирование элементами UI интерфейса требует хороших знаний о типах разметки и контейнеров, много нюансов там.
А судя по вашему коду, вы в этом сильно плаваете :)

Comment: Вы правы, в этом я не силен.  Но проект на несколько человек и все используют такой метод. Соответственно,  я тоже должен его использовать.  Из за этого другие подходы невозможны.  И еще одно: далее я буду писать onClickListener, что для канвы, как я понимаю,  не очень возможно. Так что мне все же нужно реадизовать это через ImageView

Comment: У любого View есть onTouchEvent, так что ничего невозможного нет.

Comment: А если хотите через разметку и контейнеры, научитесь располагать статически элементы в контейнере на заданных местах. Как поймете что к чему, только тогда беритесь за динамику.